# Sort a table with JavaScript after adding rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I have searched and tried many different Javascript/jQuery options but none seem to work in my case.  I have a table that I generate after a button is pushed, the table is generated row by row.

**HTML:**

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="1" id="Sort_This_Table">
  <tr>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th>Col2</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var tableRef = document.getElementById("Sort_This_Table");
if (tableRef.rows.length > 1){for(var i = tableRef.rows.length - 1; i > 0; i--){tableRef.deleteRow(i);}}

for (i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
    var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);
    var newCell  = newRow.insertCell(0);
    newCell.innerHTML = data.data[i].col1;
    newCell.style.textAlign = 'center';
    var newCell  = newRow.insertCell(0);
    newCell.innerHTML = data.data[i].col2;
    newCell.style.textAlign = 'center';
}
```

I want to be able to sort this table by clicking on the column headings "Col1" or "Col2".  Any ideas?

Comment: I really don't think you did much research, there are *plenty* of jquery-based grid/table plugins... here's one: http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1165

Comment: There are many relative topics on this kind of behaviour, none fit your needs? Why tagging question with jQuery? Because obviously, you are not using it

Comment: Nothing (that I have tried) lets me sort a table without first filling it with something and then replacing the contents.  This I can do.  however, I never know how long the table will be when the user pushes the button, that's where my issue comes into play

Comment: http://datatables.net